# Error in the checkout of a Github using Subversion with SSH - Linux Command line

Tags: github, ssh, svn, personal-access-token

Github recently enforced a no password rule with their repository access. I can't do two factor authentication, so, I am stuck with SSH keys. I want to use subversion, but when I try to checkout my repo, using:

`svn co "svn+ssh://git@github.com/Oiubrab/ozzymandais.git"`

I get the error:

```
Invalid command: 'git@github.com svnserve -t'
  You appear to be using ssh to clone a git:// URL.
  Make sure your core.gitProxy config option and the
  GIT_PROXY_COMMAND environment variable are NOT set.
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://git@github.com/Oiubrab/ozzymandais.git'
svn: E210002: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

From the research I've done, I think I need to edit the `/home/user/.subversion/config` file, but i have no idea how and there is no documentation as to how to use svn with github with ssh. I have setup an ssh key and popped it on my github account. I just need to know how to setup the subversion tunnel to github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think that github supports the `svnserve` protocol.
2. AFAIK, you should generate a personal access token (PAT) in GitHub and use it as a password in the Subversion client. I.e., enter your PAT when the client prompts you for a password.

Comment: Boom, that works. For anyone else in this situation, https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token, for the PAT setup. First, remove the old account details with `svn auth --remove Username` where 'Username' is your github username.